# Programmatically position UIView before viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got two UIViews. The first contains a variable number of UIButtons which might overflow into `two rows`. The second needs to be positioned below the first.

I have read a lot of posts like this: [How to position a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410011/how-to-position-a-uiview)

Unfortunately, these seem to only work if you call them in the `viewDidAppear:` method or later. This means that there is a short amount of time between when my views load and when my elements are correctly positioned.

How can I elegantly solve this problem?

Edit 1:
Here is a simple method I am using the adjust view2 downwards

```
-(void)adjustView:(UIView *)view down:(int)down{
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + down;
    view.frame = frame;
    }
```

Edit 2:
This is something like how I am adding my buttons, resizing my first view, and calculating how far the next one needs to go down

```
- (void)addButtonsToView:(NSArray *)buttonStrings {
    //To correctly position
    float previousTagsWidth = 0.0;
    self.adjustDown = 0.0;

    for (NSString *str in buttonStrings) {      
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setTitle:str forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];

        CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:TAG_FONT];
        if (previousTagsWidth + size.width > 300) {
            previousTagsWidth = 0;
            self.adjustDown += size.height+10;
            }

        button.frame = CGRectMake(previousTagsWidth, self.adjustDown, size.width+10, size.height+5);
        previousTagsWidth += size.width+20;

        [self.view1 addSubview:button];
        }
    CGRect frame = self.view1.frame;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height+self.adjustDown;
    self.view1.frame = frame;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `viewWillAppear` method? This is called just before your view controller's view is added to a window and lets you layout your subviews before they become visible.

Comment: @AlexMDC I have the exact same problem in viewWillAppear as I do in viewDidLoad. Same exact method in viewDidAppear works as expected.

Comment: When and how do you create your `UIButton`s?

Comment: Yes but when do you call `addButtonsToView:`? In your `viewDidLoad`, or in `viewDidAppear`? (it should be in the first)

Answer (score 5):

Why not in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? That's what I use all the time.

(Don't forget to call `super` !)

Comment: Neither of these are working for me. See my edit 1. I am calling the `super` and then calling my `adjustView` method.  Any tips?

Comment: 'viewWillLayoutSubviews' is the right place to do such things. Can you describe "not working". How are they "not working"?

Comment: Also if your layout is not too complex, consider using `autoresizingMask` in `viewDidLoad`. Worked for me 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for the human eye to realize that your views are moved in that short period of time? I would say it's not, but if you experience the opposite you can just set the `hidden` property of those views to YES(in `viewDidLoad`) and then in `viewDidAppear:` set them to not hidden (after setting their final positions).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:firstView]` or `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:secondView]` or using `didAddSubview`

Please check apple document of [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)